# jQuery: search name without spacing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm a newbie to jQuery/JavaScript. During my learning process, I found a search filter code from W3schools by using jQuery. I have tried to used it in my code and it worked well. Now, I wonder how could I get the search result without spacing when I enter the names? For example, one of my data is
'Jacky Chan', and I wish that I can get the search result by just entering 'jackychan'/'Jackyc'/'JackyChan'/'jackyc'. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
$("#myList li").filter(function() {
  $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
   });
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<br>

<ul id="myList">
  <li>Jacky Chan</li>
  <li>Lim Hai Yang</li>
  <li>Soul Wong</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some regex to your search value to check if it has a space and display your items accordingly here:

**UPDATED CODE BASED ON COMMENT:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            //get a new value that replaces all whitespace with a single space
            var newValue = value.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');

            $("#myList li").filter(function() {
                //if value has a space
                if (/\s/.test(value)) {
                    //replace all spaces in new value with an empty string
                    newValue = newValue.replaceAll(" ", "");
                    //filters the results with the new value with an empty strings for whitespaces
                    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "").indexOf(newValue) > -1);
                }else {
                    //does the same as above but filters using value only since it has no space
                    $(this).toggle($(this).text().replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<br>

<ul id="myList">
    <li>Jacky Chan</li>
    <li>Lim Hai Yang</li>
    <li>Soul Wong</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Amma. It works well. Thank you so much. Is it possible like ignore other whitespace too? For example, I can search 'limhaiyang'/'limhaiy' for 'Lim Hai Yang' or any name with more white space?

Comment: @fjs hello, glad it worked. I updated the code to match what your desired outcome will be. I also put comments explaining the code. Hope this helps!

Comment: Omg, the comments help a lot. Thanks again, Amma. Really appreciate for your helps.

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace the space with an empty string.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
$("#myList li").filter(function() {
  $(this).toggle($(this).text().replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
   });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<br>

<ul id="myList">
  <li>Jacky Chan</li>
  <li>Lim Hai Yang</li>
  <li>Soul Wong</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, Jon. I know replaceAll(" ", ""), but don't know where to add before. T.T Learnt it from you. Thank you so much.